# How to restore a GHO disk image file?

Tags: system-restore, norton-ghost, symantec-gho-explorer

Symantec GHO Explorer can open, and extract files, but to use it for a restore I would need a a live installation of Windows on a usb drive. I've also tried Symantec Ghost, but it seems that it needs a server in the same network to work.

What will restore a system partition from a GHO file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Symantec Ghost Solution Suite: https://www.symantec.com/ghost-solution-suite

Burn a CD from the image file, and boot your computer with it.

Trialware is available.